# Git merge conflicts on files that are NOT changed

Tags: git, merge, conflict

I went through the following questions already:

1. [Git merge conflicts on files that are changed by one branch only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326551/git-merge-conflicts-on-files-that-are-changed-by-one-branch-only)
2. [How to avoid getting git errors/conflicts on untouched files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193120/how-to-avoid-getting-git-errors-conflicts-on-untouched-files)
3. [Git merge conflicts when no changes done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900897/git-merge-conflicts-when-no-changes-done)

But I found no reasonable explanation. So trying to open a new thread.

**Problem**: When I merge 'master' to my developer branch (dev-branch), I get merge conflicts on files that are NOT modified by me on dev-branch.

**Procedure**:

- *git checkout master*
- *git pull --ff-only* (Update the master branch to the latest changes)
- *git checkout dev-branch*
- *git merge --squash master*
- Results in conflicts on files not modified by me

**Questions**:

1. Why do I see the conflicts ?
2. Why cannot GIT resolve them automatically since there are no changes on my branch ?
3. What can I do to avoid these conflicts ?

**===EDIT: 12th June 2019===**

I started to observe my merge behavior to narrow down on the issue and found the following. Whenever I am developing something that takes long time, I tend to update my development branch often to avoid having to do a single big shot merge.

If I was working on branch say, **dev_branch**, I used to merge **master** to **dev_branch**, and continue my development, and repeat this step every once in a while. But what I found useful is to actually merge **dev_branch** to **master** and branch out from it again to a new development branch **dev_branch_1** (note that I am not commiting anything on **master** yet since the development is not complete) and continue development on the new branch. This seems to work for me so far to avoid these nasty merge conflicts.

Comment: Could it be that you got line endings wrong? Because the reason you get conflicts is because the files *are* changed.

Comment: Definitely not line endings because when I start to resolve these conflicts they are indeed actual code changes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57145062/what-are-the-proper-use-cases-of-git-merge-squash) the problem is with `git merge --squash master`

> `git merge --squash` produces a non-merge commit. Therefore, Git will not recognize that the commit you are merging from as the merge base. This leads to unwanted merge results.

As I can imagine the first squashed commit won't have any "fake" conflicts, but the second time when you merge the master into your branch with `--squash` git cannot locate the common ancestor, it would choose the initial commit on your **dev_branch** not the one that you've already merged with the squash.
So the conflicts based on the difference between the firstly merged commit on master and the latest commit on master.